# Execute a stored procedure on selected range of rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on a range of records from nth to nth. How can I write the code to get my desired results?

This code output values for whole number of rows but I want results from rows between 100 to 300 OR 500 to 600 based on same conditions as written in code. I am working on SQL Server 2008

```
USE GERP

DECLARE @ProductID NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM STK_ProductMaster 
    WHERE ParentPCode LIKE '3%' AND Status = 'Active'

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ProductID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_GetBOMCost @ProductID

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ProductID
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: If you're talking about the 300th record, make sure you use an `ORDER BY` to get consistent results. There are many methods for _paging_ here https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: Also are you absolutely sure that you need a cursor?